# How to work around data skew problem?

Tags: apex, custom-object, master-detail, isv, architecture

We have a custom object that is a detail of Account. Every account may end up with tens of thousands of records of this object type. We have the business need to actually have those records under the account. This is not a "parking" account as suggested by [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/04/avoid-account-data-skew-for-peak-performance.html). We have thought of breaking up the account to multiple accounts though but that introduces so many complications. We also looked at the possibility of switching to lookup relationships but even that would require us to manage sharing on the child records, which is a costly overhead.

We will not need to update sharing or do not have complicated sharing configurations in the org and the only issue would be when we want to update several of the detail records in multiple jobs running at the same time. Because of the large number of child records for each account, these concurrent jobs may fail to get a lock and therefore fail to complete successfully. Does anyone have any ideas on how to scale our solution to guarantee success on all of the jobs?

Comment: You don't ask a question here. Please **[edit]** your post to actually ask something specific.

Comment: As Adrian suggests, you (still) aren't asking a specific enough question which can be answered succinctly. This document from Salesforce may be a good resource for your solutioning: [Designing Record Access for Enterprise Scale](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/draes.pdf) and all of the articles under **Data Management** here: [Architect Core Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Architect_Core_Resources)

Comment: Thank you. I do know I have a data skew problem and I do know I need to solve it. I have no leads of how to solve it, which is why the question is high level. I'll read through the documents and try to make my question more specific.